# How to find out if the loaded page is error page or valid page in System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am using

```
System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser
```

control in C# for displaying some pages. I want to do some custom work when the user clicks on a url of a page which does not exist.

Basically I want to set some values when the browser displays the following message

```
The page cannot be displayed 
 The page you are looking for is currently unavailable. The Web site might be experiencing technical difficulties
```

How can I get the status so that I can differenciate between a page loaded and error page?

Comment: This doesn't really work.  Many ISPs will just redirect to some kind of advertizing junk page.  You'd need a reputable DNS server, like 8.8.8.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cast WebBrowser to the underlying ActiveX implementation, you can access the NavigateError event.

Note: You'll need to add a reference to SHDocVw. Confusingly, this is in the COM tab with the name "Microsoft Internet Controls" with a path of c:\windows\system32\ieframe.dll

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Note: you need to wait until the ActiveXInstance property is initialised.
            var axWebBrowser = (SHDocVw.WebBrowser)webBrowser1.ActiveXInstance;
            axWebBrowser.NavigateError += axWebBrowser_NavigateError; 
            webBrowser1.Url = new Uri("http://www.thisisnotavaliddomain.com");
        }

        void axWebBrowser_NavigateError(object pDisp, ref object URL, ref object Frame, ref object StatusCode, ref bool Cancel)
        {
            //handle your error
        }
```

Comment: This works for me, saved me undue extension of the webrowser class.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `CreateSink` method on the `WebBrowser` control to access the `NavigateError` event of the underlying WebBrowser ActiveX control. The `System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser` control is a managed wrapper for the WebBrowser ActiveX control, but it does not wrap all of the functionality of that ActiveX control. The `NavigateError` event is available on the unmanaged ActiveX web browser control.  `CreateSink` will allow you to extend the functionality of the `System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser` control so you can handle the `NavigateError` event.

From the documentation:

> This method is useful if you are familiar with OLE development using
>   the unmanaged WebBrowser ActiveX control and you want to extend the
>   functionality of the Windows Forms WebBrowser control, which is a
>   managed wrapper for the ActiveX control. You can use this
>   extensibility to implement events from the ActiveX control that are
>   not provided by the wrapper control.

MSDN has a full example here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.createsink.aspx

Comment: I have not tried this, the other answer saved me the implementation of the extended class.

Comment: Glad you were able to get this working. I think my approach prevents you from having to add a reference to SHDocVw, but certainly my approach is more complicated than the other answer.

Comment: I am not a pro, but will referencing this assembly cause any problems when deploying at client or some other issues?

Comment: @CodeMe I'm not sure, but I don't think referencing the assembly will cause issues because ultimately I think that dll needs to be present on the client computer anyway. I would go with the simpler solution and if you run into issues with deployment then create a test project using my approach to see if gets around those issues.